# What's the square bracket syntax [ |- Set] in Coq?

Tags: coq

I some times see this syntax in Coq to represent certain types/sets such as in printing information about existential variables:

```
?T : [ |- Set]
?T0 : [ x : ?T |- Set ]
```

I don't know how to search for this syntax.

What does it mean?

Is the first one the same as

```
? T : Set
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose we have a term with a certain type.

```
Variable B : nat -> nat.
Check B.
(*
B
     : nat -> nat
 *)
```

If we create another term using `B` it may or may not type check, i.e. `B true` is *not* typeable.

```
Fail Check B true.
(*
 Error message:
 The term "true" has type "bool" while it is expected to have type "nat".
 *)
```

Coq allows *wildcards* in terms and then tries to figure out the type itself.

```
Check B _.
(*
B ?n
     : nat
where
?n : [ |- nat]
 *)
```

Here Coq says that the type of `B _` is `nat`, but *only
under the assumption that the argument
(named `?n`) is of type `nat`*.  Or otherwise put, "under the assumption that one can infer that the type of `?n` is `nat` from the empty context".

Sometimes more stuff is found on the left side of the "turnstile" symbol `|-`.

```
Variable x:nat.
Check _ x.
(*
?y x
     : ?T@{x:=x}
where
?y : [ |- forall x : nat, ?T] 
?T : [x : nat |- Type] 
*)
```

Above the underscore is called `?y` and the type of `(?y x)` is a dependent type `?T` that depends on `x`. `?T` is only typable (to a `Type`) in a context where `x` is a `nat`.
If `x` is not a nat, then `?T` is not typable.

Answer (score 0):

I might be mistaken, but the first one should be read as "the existential variable named `T` is of type `Set`" and the second should be read as "the existential variable named `T0` is of type `Set`, in a context where the variable `x` is of type `?T`", meaning that the term which will fill the second hole might depend on some variable named `x`.